# How to delete a Windows network interface?

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, network-interface

I don't know why but I have several network interfaces that correspond to the *Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter* :

- `Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 11`
- `Carte réseau sans fil Connexion au réseau local* 12`

Since it is useless to have several for a same thing and because I don't use Wi-Fi Direct either, I'd like to delete those network interfaces. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Right-click on the network interface, then select delete.

Comment: You can also use   .........   netsh wlan delete profile name="Profile Name"  To delete profile

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio They don't appear in the adapters list of the control panel.  
@John It doesn't work it can't find them. `netsh wlan show interfaces` only show 1 interface which is my Wi-Fi interface.

Comment: @Nicryc Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yeah, they don't appear in here but only when I execute the command: `ipconfig` or `netsh ipv4 show interfaces`.